# Subset df in pandas where value is in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like so:

```
             A  age  B   C   D   E
0            0   58  0   1   0   0   
1            0   45  0   0  99   0   
2            1   41  0   1   1   0   
3            0   53  0   1  99  99   
4            0   28  0  99   0  99
```

What I wish to do is get the subset of the df where columns B, C, D, or E equal 99, like so:

```
             A  age  B   C   D   E   
1            0   45  0   0  99   0      
3            0   53  0   1  99  99   
4            0   28  0  99   0  99
```

Tried this:

```
df99 = df[df['B'] == 99 or df['C'] == 99 or df['D'] == 99 or df['E'] == 99]
```

but that returned this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) article and did this:

```
df99 = df[(df['B'] == 99) | (df['C'] == 99) | (df['D'] == 99) | (df['E'] == 99)]
```

Replacing or with | and wrapping each argument within () solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# choose columns B-E using loc
# check if value is 99 in any of the rows

df[df.loc[:,"B":"E"].eq(99).any(axis=1)]
```

```
A   age     B   C   D   E
1   0   45  0   0   99  0
3   0   53  0   1   99  99
4   0   28  0   99  0   99
```